# How can jTable work with Symfony 2?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, jquery-jtable

I created a Datagrid with jTable, here is my JavaScript code in twig:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery('#grid').jtable({
            title: 'Table of product',
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 2,
            sorting: true,
            defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
            actions: {
                listAction: '{{path("_db_show")}}',
                createAction: '{{path("_serverproc")}}?action=create',
                updateAction: '{{path("_serverproc")}}?action=update',
                deleteAction: '{{path("_serverproc")}}?action=delete'
            },
            fields: {
                id: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                Name: {
                    title: 'Name',
                    width: '40%'
                },
                Price: {
                    title: 'Price',
                    width: '20%'
                },
                Description: {
                    title: 'Description',
                    width: '30%',
                }
            }
        });

        //Load person list from server
        $('#grid').jtable('load');

    });

</script>
```

And the following is the php code in controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/show", name="_db_show")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction()
{

    $product = array({'id' => 1, 'Name' => "test",'Price' => "200",'Description' => "ok"});
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    $jTableResult['Records'] = $product;
    $JsonResponse = new JsonResponse($jTableResult);
    return $JsonResponse;
}
```

The result I got is:

{"Result":"OK","Records":{"id":1,"Name":"test","Price":"200","Description":"ok"}}

Could someone kindly tell me what should I do to use jTable with Symfony? A working example will be great. Thank you very much.

Comment: And what issues are you facing? Any errors, what exactly doesn't work? The result seems good so far. Please provide us some more details :)

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
$product = array('id' => 1, 'Name' => "test",'Price' => "200",'Description' => "ok");
```

without {} in array definition;